# How to get items without specific params from MongoDB using Mongoose (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have NodeJS API with Mongoose to connect to MongoDB
To get all items from a collection I do this: `const users = db.users.aggregate()`

This is a example user:

```
{
    name: 'Name',
    password: '$2a$10$fe', // the password is encrypted
    email: 'email@example.com'
}
```

How can I got the same items but without the password param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the projection action from the aggregation pipeline:

```
db.users.aggregate([ {
   $project: { password: 0 } 
}])
```

Also if you're not going to use the aggregation pipeline, use the find method instead:

```
db.users.find({}, { password: 0 })
```